# в статистической среде R не исполняются sql-запросы

Tags: sql, r

Пытаюсь делать SQL-запрос через пакеь `sqldf` в среде R:

```
library(sqldf)
Загрузка требуемого пакета: gsubfn
Загрузка требуемого пакета: proto
Загрузка требуемого пакета: RSQLite
Загрузка требуемого пакета: DBI
```

Далее, смотрю табличку BOD:

```
BOD
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```

Дальше пытаюсь делать запрос:

```
x <- paste('select * from BOD where Time > 4')
x
[1] "select * from BOD where Time > 4"
sqldf(x,row.names=TRUE)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Ошибка в sqliteFetch(rs, n = -1) :
  rsqlite_query_fetch: failed first step: РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅ ...
```

В чем проблема? Я так подозреваю, что здесь что-то не так 
с кодировкой (типа utf-8), вот информация по:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] sqldf_0.4-10  RSQLite_1.0.0 DBI_0.3.1     gsubfn_0.6-6  proto_0.3-10 
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-47 tcltk_3.2.3
```

Comment: Вы не предоставили примера кода для воспроизведения ошибки. Сложно определить в чём именно причина.

Comment: Стоит попробовать сменить локаль на `Russian_Russia.1252`.

Comment: Проблема однозначно в Windows. Ошибка не воспроизводится ни в Win7, ни в Win10. 

SessionInfo() R version 3.3.0 Patched (2016-05-23 r70665)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251.

Требуется информация об установленных KB (команда systeminfo в cmd).
Я бы порыл в сторону http://skesov.ru/kak-ispravit-otobrazhenie-kirillicheskoy-kodirovki-v-windows/#i

Comment: Просьба предоставить результат выполнения в Windows команды systeminfo, которая позволить для сравнить параметры версий ОС